# SPARQL DBPedia encoding

Tags: encoding, sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso

I'm running a query on DBpedia and I'm receiving some results that apparently have the wrong encoding and characters that appear as question marks, e.g. --

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Bo?aziçi_University
```

-- where I expect to see --

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Bo%C4%9Fazi%C3%A7i_University
```

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bo%C4%9Fazi%C3%A7i_University) you can find the actual title.

You can execute my query at [`http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql`](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql)

```
PREFIX yago: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/>

SELECT ?school
WHERE
{
    { ?school rdf:type   schema:EducationalOrganization . }
    UNION
    { ?school rdf:type   yago:EducationalInstitution108276342 . }
    UNION
    { ?school rdf:type   yago:College108278169 . }
    UNION
    { ?school dbpedia:type   dbr:Public_university . }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Do I have to make any additions to my query to get the correct result? Is it data related (basically the data is wrong so nothing can be done)?

Comment: Note that this is DBpedia LIVE, which is not quite the same as DBpedia.  DBpedia's endpoint is http://dbpedia.org/sparql .

Comment: Yes I'm aware. Last time I tried I had the same problem with the endpoint you provided.

Comment: It is often helpful to raise this sort of issue directly to the teams involved, in this case optimally through the [DBpedia Discussion](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/dbpedia-discussion) and [Virtuoso Users](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/) mailing lists.

Comment: @TallTed Thank you for the suggestion and for cleaning up my post. I'll do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong.  I think that the result you're seeing is the same one as    [Boğaziçi University](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Bo%C4%9Fazi%C3%A7i_University), which also shows up in the results.  It's probably just some noise in the data.  If you ask for entities that have a literal question mark in their names, you'll see a bunch.  Here's a simplified version of your query (doesn't use **union**) that only includes those entities with a **?** in their URI:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?school WHERE
{
  values ?type { schema:EducationalOrganization
                 yago:EducationalInstitution108276342
                 yago:College108278169
                 dbr:Public_university }
  values ?hasType { rdf:type dbpedia:type }
  ?school ?hasType ?type .

  filter(contains(str(?school), "?"))
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20yago%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fclass%2Fyago%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20schema%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbpedia%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fschool%20WHERE%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3Ftype%20%7B%20schema%3AEducationalOrganization%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20yago%3AEducationalInstitution108276342%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20yago%3ACollege108278169%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbr%3APublic_university%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3FhasType%20%7B%20rdf%3Atype%20dbpedia%3Atype%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%3Fschool%20%3FhasType%20%3Ftype%20.%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20filter%28contains%28str%28%3Fschool%29%2C%20%22%3F%22%29%29%0D%0A%7D&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

You can reverse that filter and simply exclude those results, and I think you'll end up with what you want:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?school WHERE
{
  values ?type { schema:EducationalOrganization
                 yago:EducationalInstitution108276342
                 yago:College108278169
                 dbr:Public_university }
  values ?hasType { rdf:type dbpedia:type }
  ?school ?hasType ?type .

  filter(!contains(str(?school), "?"))
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20yago%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fclass%2Fyago%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20schema%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbpedia%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fschool%20WHERE%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3Ftype%20%7B%20schema%3AEducationalOrganization%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20yago%3AEducationalInstitution108276342%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20yago%3ACollege108278169%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbr%3APublic_university%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3FhasType%20%7B%20rdf%3Atype%20dbpedia%3Atype%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%3Fschool%20%3FhasType%20%3Ftype%20.%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20filter%28!contains%28str%28%3Fschool%29%2C%20%22%3F%22%29%29%0D%0A%7D&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)